# CS0234: The type or namespace name 'App_LocalResources' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I declaring my resource file

```
@using WIUT_WAD_CW2_00001569.App_LocalResources
```

But I am getting a problem

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'App_LocalResources' does not exist in the namespace 'WIUT_WAD_CW2_00001569' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Is there something wrong with above @using statement

Thank you in advance

Comment: Read again this part of the message: `are you missing an assembly reference?`

Comment: I don't understand what it means

Comment: Is `WIUT_WAD_CW2_00001569`, the name of your project / namespace